# How to add onFinish evant to the TAnimate in Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have code in Delphi 10.3.3:

```
 MainForm.Circle1.AnimateInt('Height', 150, 0.5, TAnimationType.InOut,
    TInterpolationType.Linear);
```

How to add for this animation OnFinish event like ShowMessage('Finish')

Comment: Need to know what version of Delphi you are using because since XE7 AnimateInt is deprecated and its not possible to have an animation OnFinish with that now. You have to do it a different way.

Comment: I use Delphi 10.3.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [FMX.Controls.TControl](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/FMX.Controls.TControl_Methods) methods `Animate...` are deprecated, and should not be used. You should use the `Animate...` methods of [FMX.Ani.TAnimator](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/FMX.Ani.TAnimator) instead, for example:

```
FMX.Ani.TAnimator.AnimateInt(Circle1, Height, 150, 0.5, TAnimationType.InOut, TInterpolationType.Linear);
```

But to add an `OnFinish()` event you need to take another approach, either by (A) declaring the animation in the designer or (B) creating it in code.

**(A) Declaring the animation in the designer**

In this example we create an animation for the `Height` property of a `Circle1: TCircle` object in our form.

Select the object. In the `Object Inspector` (OI) locate the `Height` property and select it. Note that it has a filmstrip symbol in the value column. That means you can animate it. Note that theres a drop down arrow in the value field. Click it and select `Create new TFloatAnimation` from the drop down menu.

In the structure pane you can see that `Circle1` now has a child object named `FloatAnimation1`. It should be selected but if not, select it. In the OI you can now see all the published properties for the animation and if you change OI to show the events, you will find settings for two events, `OnFinish` and `OnProcess`. Double-clicking creates the events for you as usual.

**(B) Create the animation in code**

1. Declare an animation object in the private section of your form as well as one or two event handlers for `OnProcess` and/or `OnFinish`. They must comply with `TNotifyEvent` (that is have one parameter, `Sender: TObject`)

```
    private
      ...
      Anim: TFloatAnimation;
      procedure AnimProcess(Sender: TObject);
      procedure AnimFinish(Sender: TObject);
```

2. In the `OnCreate` event of the form (e.g. `TForm1.FormCreate()`) create the `Anim` object and set its properties as needed, e.g.

```
    Anim:= TFloatAnimation.Create(Self);
    Anim.OnProcess := AnimProcess;
    Anim.OnFinish := AnimFinish;
    Anim.Duration := 0.9;
    Anim.StartValue := 41;
    Anim.StopValue := 150;
    Anim.Parent := Circle1; // The object that the animation will affect must be the parent
    Anim.PropertyName := 'Height';
```

In both cases write the event handlers as needed, e.g.

```
procedure TForm2.AnimFinish(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Animation finished');
end;
```